# Index Match query with if statement in the Match

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match

I'm trying a fairly simply Index Match statement between two different worksheets. What I need to add is a condition on the sheet that will match.
Effectively, I have a list of vessel names in sheet one (col C), and in sheet two, the vessel name (col C)the contract end dates (col Q) and the contract status (col AL)
In sheet one I need to return the contract end date. However, there are potential duplicates in sheet two so I only want to return the date if the contract status on the row does not say 'completed'
It's this condition that seems to not work, any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

```
=IF('Infield Vessel Contracts'!AL:AL<>"Complete",INDEX('Infield Vessel Contracts'!Q:Q,MATCH(C162,'Infield Vessel Contracts'!C:C,0)),"No Contract")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
=--('Infield Vessel Contracts'!AL:AL="completed")*INDEX('Infield Vessel Contracts'!Q:Q,MATCH(C162,'Infield Vessel Contracts'!C:C,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.   Unfortunately, I still get the wrong results sometimes (as if it is not discounting rows where the status says 'Complete'). Ideally, if it does not come back with an answer, I'd also like the return to be 'No Contract'